# Lockdown Channel command and Unlock channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

It's a strange question about lockdown channel but why this is not working?

This is the script of my lock command `msg.channel.guild.roles.everyone` if that everyone define as `@everyone`? I've seen this script in documents of discord permissions. I tried it but it's not working. And there's no error too.

```
    client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}lock`)){
        msg.channel.permissionOverwrites.create(msg.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });  
        msg.channel.send('Channel Locked')
    }else if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}unlock`)){
        msg.channel.permissionOverwrites.create(msg.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });  
        msg.channel.send('Channel Unlocked')
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the code running? Put a console.log("Running") to make sure

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've seen the error now. It says `Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.` @MrMythical

Answer (score 1):

```
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});
```

Unlocked the channel use

```
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: null
});
```

**for example**

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "lock")) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return;
    if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
      return;
    message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false
    });
     const lock = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     
      .setColor("#00000")
      .setDescription(
        ` | Locked Channel
❯ **Channel Name :** <#${message.channel.id}>
❯ **Locked By :** <@${message.author.id}>
`
      )
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
     .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.avatarURL())
          .setTimestamp()

    message.chaneel.send(lock);
  }
});
```

***This is embed***

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. So I tried your given code. There's alot of error such as `hasPermission` but that's okay I changed it because I'm using v13, But this `updateOverwrite`, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: ```message.channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS'],
  },
]);```

Comment: Its working fine for me